Is it intended behaviour that the screen gets locked when a DP monitor is turned off?
When the pc is attached to a single screen via Display Port and that monitor is turned off, Ubuntu 24.04 locks the screen. This was not the case in 22.04, if I recall correctly. I'm wondering if this is intended behavior, since any program running is killed on lock.

You may disable the lock feature.

I wouldn't think so. May the Gnome folks (which have crippled the Linux UI for more than a decade now) thought this is a cool feature. It will  have to be a "udev -rule" to be disabled though. Do you have that behavior, if using the XServer session instead of the default "wayland" Ubuntu session?

@kanehekili it is a gnome issue. Although the default session already seems to be X11

No, default Ubuntu 24.04 is Wayland. Log out select the cog icon on the bottom right side and select Xsession

Looks like gnome interprets a powered off DP monitor as a blank screen. After switching off the setting under Privacy & Security > Screen Lock > Automatic Screen Lock and starting a new session the problem is gone, although this is not optimal, since an actual blank screen won't lock the pc either.
